# TikZ: sffamily for pgfmathprintnumber

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

How can I get `\sffamily` for a `\pgfmathprintnumber`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\Huge\sffamily, % wanted
align=left
]
\node[draw, label={1.23}]{good\\ 1.23};

\node[xshift=3cm, draw, label={\pgfmathprintnumber[]{1.23}},
]{bad \\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{1.23}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED to avoid losing format information. What I did is create a macro

```
\newcommand\pgfmathsfprintnumber[2][]{%
  \pgfmathprintnumberto[#1]{#2}\z 
  \expandafter\zz\z}
\newcommand\zz[2]{#1{\mathsf{#2}}}
```

that sends the `\pgfmathprintnumber` not to be typeset, but placed in a macro `\z`.  It is of the format `\pgfutilensuremath{1.23}`.  So what I do is absorb two arguments and re-express them as `\pgfutilensuremath{\mathsf{1.23}}`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\newcommand\pgfmathsfprintnumber[2][]{%
  \pgfmathprintnumberto[#1]{#2}\z 
  \expandafter\zz\z}
\newcommand\zz[2]{#1{\mathsf{#2}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\Huge\sffamily, % wanted
align=left
]
\node[draw, label={1.23}]{good\\ 1.23};

\node[xshift=3cm, draw, label={\pgfmathsfprintnumber{1.23}},
]{bad \\ \pgfmathsfprintnumber[fixed]{1.23}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Helps me good. ;)